# Infinite while loop sometimes breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I wrote a little crypto switcher which checks profit and switches miners. But it works some time and then the loop stops without any error (it may work 15 min or 20 hours but it will stop, tested for 10 days).

code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import time
import copy
import requests
import configparser
from datetime import datetime


def config_read ():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    return config.sections


def start_miner(info):
    if info['algorithm'] == 'Equihash':
        subprocess.Popen('F:\Claymore\start — music — Peon.bat', cwd='F:\Claymore',
                         creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
    elif info['algorithm'] == 'Ethash':
        subprocess.Popen('F:\Claymore\start — music — Peon.bat', cwd='F:\Claymore',
                         creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
    return info


def stop_miner():
    os.system("taskkill /f /t /im  miner.exe")
    os.system("taskkill /f /t /im  EthDcrMiner64.exe")


def request_coins():
    coins = None
    while coins is None:
        try:
            coins = ((requests.get(
                url='https://whattomine.com/coins.json?utf8=✓&eth=true&factor%5Beth_hr%5D=79.0&factor%5Beth_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bgro_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bgro_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bx11g_hr%5D=20.0&factor%5Bx11g_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bcn_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bcn_p%5D=0.0&eq=true&factor%5Beq_hr%5D=1000.0&factor%5Beq_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Blrev2_hr%5D=80000.0&factor%5Blrev2_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bns_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bns_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Blbry_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Blbry_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bbk2b_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bbk2b_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bbk14_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bbk14_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bpas_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bpas_p%5D=0.0&bkv=true&factor%5Bbkv_hr%5D=0.0&factor%5Bbkv_p%5D=0.0&factor%5Bcost%5D=0.06&sort=Profitability24&volume=0&revenue=24h&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=bittrex&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=bleutrade&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=btc_e&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=bter&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=c_cex&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=cryptopia&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=poloniex&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=yobit&dataset=Main&commit=Calculate&adapt_q_280x=0&adapt_q_380=0&adapt_q_fury=0&adapt_q_470=0&adapt_q_480=0&adapt_q_750Ti=0&adapt_q_10606=3&adapt_q_1070=0&adapt_q_1080=0&adapt_q_1080Ti=0%27')).json())[
            'coins']
        except:
            print("Site didn't respond. Reconnecting in 10 sec")
            time.sleep(10)
    return coins


def miner_chose(config, info):
    user_coins = {}
    coins = request_coins()
    for key, value in config['Currency'].items():
        if value == 'True':
            tag = key.upper()
            for key_coin, value_coin in coins.items():
                if value_coin['tag'] == info['temp_currency']:
                    info['temp_profit'] = value_coin['btc_revenue24']
                if value_coin['tag'] == info['currency']:
                    info['profit'] = value_coin['btc_revenue24']
                if value_coin['tag'] == tag:
                    user_coins[key_coin] = value_coin
    for key, value in user_coins.items():
        if float(value['btc_revenue24']) >= float(info['profit']) * (float(config['CheckOptions']['profitprocent']) +100) / 100:
            if not info['currency'] == value['tag']:
                if float(value['btc_revenue24']) > float(info['temp_profit']):
                    if not info['temp_currency'] == value['tag']:
                        info['check_times'] = 0
                    info['temp_profit'] = value['btc_revenue24']
                    info['temp_currency'] = value['tag']
                info['check_times'] += 1
                if int(info['check_times']) >= int(config['CheckOptions']['times']):
                    info['profit'] = value['btc_revenue24']
                    info['currency'] = value['tag']
                    info['algorithm'] = value['algorithm']
                    info['check_times'] = 0
    return info
```

Part of code that uses while loop and stops:

```
def main():
    info = {'profit': 0, 'check_times': 200, 'currency': None, 'temp_profit': 0, 'temp_currency': None}
    config = config_read()

    while True:
        if info['profit'] == 0:
            stop_miner()
            info = start_miner(miner_chose(config,info))
            print(str(datetime.now()) + " - Starting miner first time. Currency: " + info['currency'] + '. Profit: ' +
                  info['profit'] + ' BTC/Day')
            time.sleep(int(config['CheckOptions']['period']) * 60)
        else:
            old_info = copy.deepcopy(info)
            info = miner_chose(config, info)
            print(
                str(datetime.now()) + ' - Checking profit. Current currency: ' + info['currency'] + '. Profit: ' + info[
                    'profit'] + ' BTC/Day')
            if info['currency'] != old_info['currency']:
                print('Changing miner. Currency ' + info['currency'] + '. Profit: ' + info['profit'] + ' BTC/Day')
            elif info['currency'] == old_info['currency']:
                print('Curency SAME')
                # stop_miner()
                # start_miner(info)
            time.sleep(int(config['CheckOptions']['period']) * 60)
```

I want that after sleeping  `time.sleep(int(config['CheckOptions']['period']) * 60)` script have to start again and make all check again but sometimes script sleep for time i have put in config and don't want to check again. It may stop after 10 or 20 check without any errors.

Comment: What loop? There are multiple.

Comment: This is too much code. Only post the relevant part and describe the problem clearly

Comment: leave full code but add while loop which stops.

Comment: Since I never trust programmers, especially not myself, I would put a print statement after the loop, print ('exiting normally - unreachable code'). If that text shows up in your console, then you have some evidence that it's doing what you think, rather than simply exiting for some other reason like an exception or taskkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add  to `coins = ((requests.get(url='https://whattomine.com/coins.json', timeout=3)).json())['coins']` cause the server something stack and don't send response.